# GLSL's imageLoad() always returns 0?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have created a texture and filled it with some data:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, head_pointer_image);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32UI, width, height, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, data);
```

Then I bound it to 0:

```
glBindImageTexture(0, head_pointer_image, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_R32UI); 
glUniform1ui(0, 0); // Not sure if necessary
```

If I check the data with glGetTexImage() I get correct values, but if I try to read it in my shader, I only get zeros.

```
layout(binding = 0, r32ui) coherent uniform uimage2D head_pointer_image;

uint value = imageLoad(head_pointer_image, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy)).r;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried changing coherent to readonly?

Comment: Yes, nothing changed.

Comment: Instead of `ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy)` try with hard-coded values, so as to discard other causes.

Comment: I think change to readonly in shader will need change in call to glBindImageTexture(0, head_pointer_image, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_ONLY, GL_R32UI);

Comment: @Ripi2 I tried, but still nothing. 
Have also changed to GL_READ_ONLY. I am not getting any errors with glGetError() either.

Comment: Try using `glTexStorage2D` before `glTexImage2D`

Comment: Try deleting that `glUniform1ui(0, 0)`

Comment: What if you write "uniform" before "layout(...)" ?

Comment: @Ripi2 You mean glTexStorage2D instead of glTexImage2D? I can't use both right? Replacing it didn't change anything. Tried the other suggestions too and still only zeros.

Comment: @RhuMage Yes, you can define the storage **and** later change (by glTexImage..) the data. I've run out of ideas. Perhaps seeing the full code reveals hidden cause...

Comment: @Ripi2 Here's my code: 

https://github.com/Rhumage/imageLoad/blob/master/opengltest/Engine.cpp
https://github.com/Rhumage/imageLoad/blob/master/opengltest/shaders/second.fs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have received outside help, the problem was that my texture was incomplete due to the default minification filtering being GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR which requires a full mipmap chain and I only had the base level image.

Setting GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER to GL_LINEAR fixed my issue.